# webkitRelativePath is empty while saving image in indexed db

Tags: indexeddb

I am trying to save a file with text data . the text data is saving but the link the webkitRelativePath path is showing empty in the indexed db is this the code of my adding data into indexed db

```
   function add() {
        var a = document.getElementById("userfile");
        var b = a.files[0];
            var request = db.transaction(["todostore"], "readwrite")
            .objectStore("todostore")
            .add({ timestamp: "KP" + (new Date()).getTime(), todo: $("#todo").val(),
            price:$("#toprice").val(),image:b});

         };
```

[Webkit Empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkPbl.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `webkitRelativePath` property is not (as yet) standardized, and is not part of the definition of `File` in the [File API](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/) standard. It is not cloned along with other properties.

There is an effort to [standardize](https://wicg.github.io/entries-api/) it (I'm the author of the proposal, which documents part of Chrome's behavior) but it does not yet define the structured clone behavior for the property, and browsers that implement it do not clone it.

To make this work today you'll need to store the value as a property on another object.